# Get quarters months from random 2 years start and end date range in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have one date range called start_date(202204) and end_date(202403) and I want to calculate 8 quarter in 8 different variable like

```
prior_q1_month = "202204, 202205, 202206"
prior_q2_month = "202207, 202208, 202209"
prior_q3_month = "202210, 202211, 202212"
prior_q4_month = "202301, 202302, 202303"
recent_q1_month = "202304, 202305, 202306"
recent_q2_month = "202307, 202308, 202309"
recent_q3_month = "202310, 202311, 202312"
recent_q4_month = "202401, 202402, 202403"
```

So it doesn't matter whatever month we are in, it should always calculate last quarter last month is end_date and -24 is start_date and value should gets updated in each variable.

here is what I tried but it has hard code value which is not helping me get dynamic result.

```
start_of_quarter = datetime(year=datetime.now().year, month=((math.floor(((datetime.now().month - 1) / 3) + 1) - 1) * 3) + 1, day=1).strftime('%Y/%m/%d')

start_date = (datetime.strptime(start_of_quarter, '%Y/%m/%d') - relativedelta(months=24)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') 

end_date = (datetime.strptime(start_of_quarter, '%Y/%m/%d') - relativedelta(months=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') 

start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")

months = {}
while start_date <= end_date:
    quarter = (start_date.month-1)//3 + 1
    year = start_date.year
    key = f"{'prior' if year == 2022 else 'recent'}_q{quarter}_month"
    if key not in months:
        months[key] = []
    months[key].append(start_date.strftime("%Y%m"))
    start_date += relativedelta(months=1)
    
for key, values in months.items():
    print(f'{key} = "{",".join(values)}"')
```

Comment: What would the output look like if start_date == 202202 ?